# How to get the index of any array matching an exact text in Google Apps Script?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

How can I get the index of any array having 'AAPL' in the following example code?  The following code returned true or false.  Instead of true or false, how can I get 0 and 2?  Thanks for any help!

```
function test() {
  var tickers = [], isAAPL = [];
  tickers[0] = 'AAPL';
  tickers[1] = 'GOOG';
  tickers[2] = 'AAPL';
  tickers[3] = 'MSFT';
  // how to find the index of the array containing 'AAPL'?  The output should be 0 and 2.
  isAAPL = tickers.map(x => (x == 'AAPL'));
  console.log(isAAPL);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function test() {
  let tickers = ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'];
  let found = [];
  let start = '';
  var idx = '';
  do {
    idx = tickers.indexOf('AAPL', start);
    if (~idx) {
      found.push(idx);
      start = idx + 1;
    }
  } while (~idx)
  console.log(found.join(','));
}

Execution log
2:25:24 PM  Notice  Execution started
2:25:25 PM  Info    0,2
2:25:25 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

This works too:

```
function test1() {
  var tickers = [], isAAPL = [];
  tickers[0] = 'AAPL';
  tickers[1] = 'GOOG';
  tickers[2] = 'AAPL';
  tickers[3] = 'MSFT';
  // how to find the index of the array containing 'AAPL'?  The output should be 0 and 2.
  isAAPL = tickers.map((x,i) => {if(x == 'AAPL')return i;}).filter(e => !isNaN(e) );
  console.log(isAAPL.join(','));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach - a slight variation on the first approach in cooper's answer:

```js
var tickers = ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'];
var symbol = 'AAPL';
var idx = tickers.indexOf(symbol);
var isAAPL = [];
while (idx != -1) {
  isAAPL.push(idx);
  idx = tickers.indexOf(symbol, idx + 1);
}
console.log(isAAPL);
```

This uses [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) in a loop to repeatedly find the "next" occurrence.

Each time it starts at the position following the last position where the string was found.